# Why are crystalline structures in solids so common?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry-breaking, crystals, lattice-model

Is there any sort of theorem or paper that shows that periodic arrays gives ground states? Or any other theoretical reason why crystals are so common?

Comment: I would say that this is dictated by thermodynamic: H=T*S. If you move from a disorderd arrangment to an ordered one, S decreases and hence H becomes negative. The process is exothermic. Conversely, you have an endothermic process and you must supply energy.

Comment: Check out Wigner crystals: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_crystal

Comment: Consider what you mean by "so common in solids". What about polymers or glassy ceramics? What about beeswax and wood? What is unique about certain chemical substances that they do not form crystalline structures as solids?

Answer (score 2):

(Since several weeks have passed without the requested rigorous proof, I'll give the hand-wavy reasoning that came to mind.)

Given that certain bond angles are favorable, it makes intuitive sense to aim to reproduce them identically at every atom. This is equivalent to periodicity.

Even if certain bond angles *aren't* favorable, periodic stacking (e.g., in [face-centered-cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system) crystals) still puts each atom as close as it would like to be to its neighbor, which is ideal.

However, this reasoning—enthalpic minimization—doesn't give the whole picture. At constant temperature and pressure, it's not the enthalpy $H$ but the Gibbs free energy $G\equiv H-TS$ that's minimized, as also affected by the temperature $T$ and entropy $S$. A higher-entropy that sacrifices some bonding benefits might be favored, especially at higher temperatures. This is why everything becomes a gas upon sufficient heating, even though a periodic solid features excellent bonding.

Furthermore, the periodic state may be thermodynamically favorable but kinetically limited; this is the general reason why we see amorphous solids around us. These so-called glasses want to be crystals.